# Triggering Android Camera from a webview, after gaining permissions to do so

Tags: android, android-camera, hybrid-mobile-app

I wonder if anyone would be able to explain this strange behaviour.

I have a hybrid android app, that up to Android 5, successfully invoked a camera/folder dialog following a click on an html input element defined as follows:

```
<input id="InputImgFileDialog" style="display:none" accept="image/*" capture="camera" type="file"/>
```

As part of my upgrade to Android 6, I replaced the onclick function with a callback to the java wrapper code to implement the required permission checks.

If these are completed successfully, I then use webView.evaluateJavascript to return to the webview and execute an automated .click() on the input element above to get back to where I was prior to Android 6, however:

1. The camera/folder dialog never appears in this case.
2. The camera/folder dialog does not even appear if it is activated later using a timeout set by the evaluateJavascript.
3. BUT the camera/folder dialog DOES appear if I use the evaluateJavascript to display a webview dialog that the user can then use to trigger the camera.

Is case 1 because the java code is hung waiting for a return from the evaluate Javascript?

I thought this was the case until I tried case 2, first a 100 and then a 1000 millsecond timeout and neither of these worked. I noticed that the actual return to java took about 20 millseconds.

I ended up with case 3 which is good enough for me by first noticing that I could actually trigger the onclick successfully from the Chrome debugger and it worked fine, but I am puzzled about why case 2 did not work. Is the evaluateJavascript waiting for everything it initiates to complete?